# How to store data of a specific column from a csv file to a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

How can i store data of a specific column in a csv file for example Name, in a list using python?
When i try to output
It output repeatedly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcEQ0.jpg)

Please help

Comment: Please format your picture to be visible for other than a link to your code snippet. Or you can add your code snippets in " ``` " enclosing quotation marks. For more on how to add picture check here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853/6021740

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('names.csv')
names = df['Name'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

```py
import csv

with open("names.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")

    # List comprehension
    csv_list = [line[0] for line in csv_reader]
```

The "0" in `line[0]` can be changed to be whichever column is desired.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filepath_here')

your_list = df['Name'].tolist()
```